# Jquery wont pass numbers to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax-request

Everytime i try to submit my form it only returns "E" and only "E", i don't know why this is happening, can anyone help me with this issue?.

i've tried a number of ways and i can;t seem to get the result it should return

**codes**

Jquery:

```
        $('#edit_ok_btn').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#NoticeBox').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500, function() {
    $('#NoticeBox').show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
    $('#NoticeBox').removeClass()
    $('#NoticeBox').addClass('Box_Working')
    $('#noticeText').html("Processing page...");

    var formData = $('#EditorForm').serialize();
    submitWebPage(formData);



    });
});

    function submitWebPage(formData) {

$.ajax({    
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'PageProcessor.php',       
    data : {'formdata' : formData},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    timeout: 7000,
    success: function(data) {   


    $('#NoticeBox').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500, function() {

        if(data.error == false)
        {
            $('#NoticeBox').show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
            $('#NoticeBox').removeClass()
            $('#NoticeBox').addClass('Box_Success')
            $('#noticeText').html(data.msg);
            $('#PageEditor').fadeOut(1000);

            $('#NoticeBox').delay(1000).hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500, function() {
            location.reload();
            });



        }
        else
        {
            $('#NoticeBox').show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
            $('#NoticeBox').removeClass()
            $('#NoticeBox').addClass('Box_Error')
            $('#noticeText').html(data.error);
        }

    }); 

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    $('#responder').removeClass().addClass('Box_Error').html('<p>There was an ERROR!<strong></p>');


    }
});
```

PHP

```
$PageID         = $_POST['formdata']['EditID'];
$PageTitle      = $_POST['formdata']['PageTitle'];
$PageCategory   = $_POST['formdata']['CategoryList'];
$PageContent    = $_POST['formdata']['elm1'];
$PagePublished  = $_POST['formdata']['PublishPageOption'];

if($PageID == "NEW")
{

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Web_Pages (Title, HTML, Category, Last_Author, Edit_Date, Published) VALUES ('".$PageTitle."','". $PageContent."','".$PageCategory."','LUX','".date("Y-m-d")."','".$PagePublished."') ");

        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['msg'] = '<i>'.$PageTitle.'</i> has been created successfully.'; 
        echo json_encode($return);
}
else
{
    mysqli_query("UPDATE Web_Pages SET Title = '".$PageTitle."', HTML = '".$PageContent."', Category = '".$PageCategory."', Last_Author='LUX', Edit_Date = '".date("Y-m-d")."', Published = '".$PagePublished."') WHERE ID = '".$PageID."' ");

        $return['error'] = false;
        $return['msg'] = '<i>'.$PageTitle.'</i> has been updated successfully.'; 
        echo json_encode($return);
}
```

[**paste-bin link to the source code**](http://pastebin.com/S9PuieDs)

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` functions, as they are no longer maintaned and are in the process of deprecation. Google, PDO or Mysqli instead

Comment: @PHPNooB, thanks for the tip, i'll do some research on it later!.

Comment: copy the update sql command into phpmyadmin, put in real values, and see if it works there.

Comment: @michi it works, if you look at the code you see that it returns the page title, and i am not getting that return value so it's really not the SQL that is my concern, it is that it does not pass the values.

Comment: @LUX: ok, then put your sql command into `$sql` and do `var_dump($sql)`, post the output

Comment: @michi won;t be mutch use since IT CAN'T GET THE VALUES

Comment: @LUX: now I read the title, finally ;-) jquery-problem... don't know about it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `)` near the end of the `UPDATE` query that shouldn't be there, most likely the result of a copy/paste/edit where you forgot the edit.

Comment: @kloink, thanks i did miss that!, but that does not solve the problem of the values though.

Answer (score 0):

im tired of this mistake !

```
 data: 'formData',
```

this will be now treated as string not a variable

i guess you should do something like this

```
data : {'formdata' : formData}
```

from php you can get the data with

```
$_POST['formdata'];
```

Comment: i'm sorry to burst your bubble... but that doesn't work either, just tried it

Comment: if this didnt solve your problem ..! then you have some other problem .. cuz apparently you were doing the whole thing wrong from the start.. use print_r($_POST) , and show us the out put .. and try to get the data from php with `$_POST['formdata']['PageTitle']`

Comment: all that the output is with that code is "E" no matter what i type it just returns "E"

Comment: you see a page with `E` only ??!!

Comment: yup, the return value for every single value is "E" nothing more also i did get it to work before and i didnt mess with the front end (jquery) i only added code lines into the php file and for some reason it decides not to work anymore

Comment: haha, thats a lot of code i would have to move over, is there a way i can send you a PM message?

Comment: trim it down , to whats necessary

Comment: well if there is a way to send a message or something to you in private i wouldn't mind adding you on skype or even just teamviewer so you have a better and live view of the code even while debugging. but i'll do my best to trim it down.

Comment: no just post it up here , so ppl get the solution along with you